# Ошибка при установке webview библиотеки в Golang

Tags: linux, golang, gui, webview, gtk+

Я выполняю команду:

```
go get github.com/zserge/webview
```

И получаю такой вывод:

```
# pkg-config --cflags  -- gtk+-3.0 webkit2gtk-4.0
Package gtk+-3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-3.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'gtk+-3.0', required by 'virtual:world', not found
Package 'webkit2gtk-4.0', required by 'virtual:world', not found
pkg-config: exit status 1
```

Работаю на Linux, пакеты `gtk+` и `webkit2gtk` установлены.
Подскажите как исправить ошибку.

UPD:
По совету @Hellseher выполнил `echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH` и получил пустую строку:

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Добавте в вопрос `echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH`

Comment: @Hellseher, похоже здесь и правда что-то не так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно было установить "devel" версии пакетов `gtk+` и `webkit2gtk`.